# Saving data that's being sent to a process through TCP/IP

Tags: sockets, process, tcp, packet-sniffers

I want to capture and save the data that's being sent to a certain process through internet .

Are there any tools for the job?

If not, does listening to the same port as the process that I'm trying to get data from, will get me the data?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, use [Winsock Packet Editor (WPE)](http://wpepro.net/). You will be able to hook a process' all Winsock-related functions and capture (and even modify/block) any TCP/IP, UDP packets that the application receives or sends. For all other operating systems, you will have to either:

1. write your own tool that hooks various socket functions (e.g. send, recv, etc.)
2. or just use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which will capture all Layer-3 packets that goes through your network card. You will have to use your own knowledge of the application that you're trying to monitor in order to filter the packets that are specific to the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/
Or RawCap: http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap
I don't know what is the data format you are trying to capture. I used these two tools to capture xml data from web service.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any tools for the job?

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html). But what have you tried?

> If not, does listening to the same port as the process that i'm trying to get data from, will get me the data?

Not if you don't forward the traffic to the real destination, otherwise the other party will be waiting forever on a response, or simply timeout and close the connection. You should create something like a proxy.

Wireshark is easier.